# Нужна ли запятая после "ну"?

Tags: пунктуация

- Главное — завершить начатое. Ну и еще большую кастрюлю молочного супа сварить.
- Лиза никак не решит задачу. Ну простенькая, а никак.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос 1. Наличие запятой зависит от смысла контекста. Можно предположить: **Главное — завершить начатое. Ну и еще (= а также, вдобавок) большую кастрюлю молочного супа сварить.**

**Похожие примеры из Нацкорпуса**

**1) Ну и ещё  (= а также, вдобавок)**

Ну и ещё кое-какие дела тут уладить. Ну и еще куча всяких мелочей. Ну и еще пара ничего не значащих фраз. Вивальди, Бах. Ну и еще много разного.

**2) Ну, и еще (перечисление, автор как бы вспоминает весь перечень)**

Ну, и еще белая одежда лучше светится под лучами прожекторов. Ну, и еще что-то, без чего совсем нельзя. Ну, и еще, конечно, я был молод, и совершить это небольшое восхождение не составляло для меня никакого труда.

Вопрос 2. **Лиза никак не решит задачу. Ну простенькая, а никак.**

Частица НУ используется для придания высказыванию большей силы, выразительности, подчёркивает значение того или другого слова.

Answer (score 2):

> Ну и еще большую кастрюлю молочного супа сварить.

Запятая в сочетании *ну и* не ставится.

> Ну простенькая, а никак.

Тут *ну* — частица, усиливающая высказывание. Не требует постановки знаков препинания.

Подробнее о пунктуации при *ну* [написано](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_501) на Грамоте.ру.

Comment: "Ну и" здесь вовсе не "неразложимое сочетание". Совсем не то же, что в "ну и что", например.

Comment: @Niemand почему?

Comment: Подходит вот это значение:.      4. ... ... Подчёркивает заключительный характер высказывания. Ну, и гости разъехались. Ну, этим дело и кончилось. Ну, я пойду. Ну, пора чай пить

Comment: @Niemand Запятая не ставится внутри неразложимых сочетаний со словами «ну тебя», «ну вас», «ну его», «ну их», а также сочетаний «ну и», «ну уж», «ну уж и».

Comment: @Niemand здесь еще приведен контекст, в котором, на мой взгляд, никакого заключительного характера нет.

Comment: *Запятая в неразложимом сочетании ну и не ставится.* - здесь могут быть разные трактовки. Чтобы не лезть в дебри, Грамота (и воде бы Кузнецов)) считает его неразложимым сочетанием http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_501, но мне такой подход не нравится. Тут скорее всего сочетание двух усилительных частиц, поскольку значение "ну и" ***вытекает*** из значения составляющих. .К тому же "И" тут с неменьшим успехом можно считать союзом, а не усилительной частицей. Тогда трактовка вообще иная. На пунктуацию это, впрочем, не влияет.

Comment: *ну — частица, усиливающая высказывание* - здесь тоже не все так ясно. Зависит от интонации.

Comment: @behemothus разве похоже на междометие?

Comment: Во втором случае - возможно. см. мой ответ.

Answer (score 2):

В двух словах: запятые не требуются. 
Если нет твердой уверенности, что автор хочет их видеть, то и думать нечего.

> Ну и еще большую кастрюлю молочного супа сварить.

Здесь можно по-разному трактовать "ну и". Или как неразложимое сочетание (мне такой подход не нравится, ибо много натяжек), или как сочетание двух частиц, или даже как частицы и союза. Ни в одном случае запятая не требуется. Единственная мотивация для запятой была бы при трактовке "междометие + частица", но здесь такое крайне маловероятно, поскольку "ну" существенно сказывается на смысле фразы, следовательно, не может быть просто междометием (междометие "ну" может быть только модальным, выражающим **отношение** говорящего к событию).

Для дальнейшего анализа контекста маловато.

> Ну простенькая, а никак.

А вот здесь я как раз допускаю запятую как авторский знак. Частица (без запятой) выражает усиление, междометие (с запятой) - чувство (иронию, например, а то и некоторое недовольство обременением). Здесь есть достаточный контекст, поэтому видно, что автор вправе распоряжаться пунктуацией - а через неё смыслом.

Comment: Хоть бы одну ссылочку на справочник. Сам себе грамматика, любезный @behemothus?

Comment: Да-да, И вас с Новым годом! Буду вам признателен.